# Updating single specified values from another table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update

I have two SQLite tables `A` and `B` defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE A (orig_cat INTEGER, type INTEGER,gv_ID INTEGER);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (3,2);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (4,2);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (1,3);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (2,3);
INSERT INTO A (orig_cat,type) VALUES (3,3);
UPDATE A SET gv_ID=rowid+99;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE B (col_t INTEGER, orig_cat INTEGER, part INTEGER);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3,1,2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2,2,1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,2,2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3,3,1);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (4,3,2);
```

I'd like to update and set/replace the values in column `col_t` of table `B` where `part=2` with selected values of column `gv_ID` of table `A`. The selected values I can get with a `SELECT` command:

```
SELECT gv_ID 
FROM (SELECT * FROM B where part=2) AS B_sub 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM A WHERE type=3) AS A_sub 
  ON B_sub.orig_cat=A_sub.orig_cat;
```

How can I use that so that the values of `col_t` in rows 2,3 and 5 (=1,2,3) get replaced with the values 104,105,106 (wich is returned by the selection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE B
SET col_t = (SELECT gv_ID FROM A WHERE A.orig_cat = B.orig_cat AND A.type = 3)
WHERE B."part" = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e6be9/1/0)**</kbd>

I've assumed that pair `A.orig_cat` and `A.type` is `UNIQUE`.